# How can I add a semi-transparant vertical plane in 3D plot in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a three dimensional plot with a data file which is successfully plotted using Gnuplot. Now within that plot I have to add a semi-transparent vertical plane like parallel to xz plane at a value of y which should cut the xy-plane perpendicularly. I cannot make the plot of such plane in the 3D plot in GNUPLOT. Please help me with this.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Take inspiration from http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/zerror.html :

```
set style fill  transparent solid 0.75 noborder
splot [][][-2:10] sin(x+y) w pm3d
xplane=0
repl '+' u (xplane):1:(-2):(-2):(10) w zerrorfill
```

Of course then you may want to have the other function in front of plane. You can replot the part of it that shouldn't be hidden:

```
rep sin(x+y)*((x>xplane)?1:1/0) w pm3d
```

(change sign if view is rotated)[image]